# Could someone explain attached M-bus master circuit?

Tags: integrated-circuit, bjt, bus

[image: m-bus master]

Could someone explain attached m-bus bjt circuit in details?
Is this a repeater of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

This is an RS232 to M-Bus Converter/Repeater.  M-Bus format is used in Europe for automated meter reading.  Basically it converts an RS232 signal into a 2-wire +-15v signal.

Here is a similar schematic with some additional explanation:
https://code.google.com/p/iotsys/wiki/MBusConnector

Comment: Hi Nedd, I already know what this circuit does. I just wanted if someone could breakdown the repeater and explain to me.